# How do I escape a MySql reserved name in ActiveRecord Relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, arel

I'm working with an older (rails 4) code base and I've been tasked with updating the mysql2 gem to support the latest db version.  With our current version of the gem and code, everything works fine, but when upgrading I'm running into a naming conflict with the reserved word, 'groups'.

I've managed to escape it with backticks in all but one query. We call `<modelname>.send(name, args)`, and when `name` is `:groups`, we get an error. The send returns an active record relation.  The relation.to_sql shows me it's all escaped but for one thing, the final `groups` which appears to be tacked onto the end of a select * from a union of selects:

```sql
SELECT `groups`.* 
  FROM 
( 
   (SELECT `groups`.* 
      FROM `groups` 
      WHERE ...) 
   UNION ALL 
   (SELECT `groups`.* 
      FROM `groups` 
      WHERE ...) 
) groups
```

I've been trying to find a way to escape that last groups reference.  The only way I can think of is to just turn this into Arel sql and run the query that way.
Is there some kind of 'name' I can pass to the ActiveReccord relation so it gives me an escaped `groups`?

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Is that expressible as normal `belongs_to` or `has_many` type relations?

Comment: Why do you need to `union` those sub queries and cannot use an `or` condition? And why the outer `select` wrapping the `union`? Did you consider simplifying the query and translating it into a Rails Active Record Query? Something like `Group.where(...).or(Group.where(...))`

Comment: @tadman the inner queries I recognize from default scope in the group.rb, which were able to be escaped: scope: { where `group`.org_id ...} The `groups` method was called on the organization which `has_many`

Comment: @spickermann this is run inside an iterable loop and I don't know how many times it will iterate.  I will probably end up just turning it to Arel and finding the final word and escaping it with a `gsub`

Comment: @tadman sorry, my previous comment is not clear.  This is part of a `has_many` relationship ... organization has_many groups, group belongs_to organization

Comment: A name like `groups` is bound to be trouble, as it's now a reserved keyword in MySQL 8.0.2. Is there any way to change that name?

Comment: Yep I agree ... this was written nearly a decade ago and I have no idea why the reserved word wasn't considered then, my lot is just to deal with it now.  There's too much risk involved in renaming it now, so I'll just gsub out that one and escape it.  The code is apparently all going to be replaced with micro services sometime in the next year anyway ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go for out of the box solutions:

- Rename the table.  If yours is the only application then this would be ideal.
- Make a view of the table and use that.  If you have other applications using the table then this might be the way to go.  Make a view of it and do all rails access through the view.  You get to have your cake and eat it.  It just adds a little complexity that you could avoid by simply renaming the table.